# CakePHP 3.5: How to convert xml reponse to app response using php

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I am using CakePHP framework and getting the response using HttpClient(cakephp). I try to convert xml to php but it return empty object while using this function SimpleXMLElement()

```
<soap:envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:body>
    <getaccountbalanceresponse xmlns="http://PegPayTelecomsApi/">
        <getaccountbalanceresult>
            <balance>xxx</balance>
            <statusdesc>xxxx</statusdesc>
            <statuscode>xxxx</statuscode>
        </getaccountbalanceresult>
    </getaccountbalanceresponse>
</soap:body>
```

How can I convert xml to php. Anyone can help me..

My php code is

```
$this->client = new Client();
    $this->response->statusCode(200);

    $this->RequestHeader = [
        'headers' => [
            'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
            'content-type' => 'text/xml',
        ],
        'ssl_verify_peer' => false,
        'ssl_verify_host' => false,
        'ssl_verify_peer_name' => false,
    ];

    $this->OAuthUrl = 'https://test.pegasus.co.ug:8019/pegpaytelecomsapi/PegPayTelecomsApi.asmx';


    $this->RequestAccessBody = '<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
    <GetAccountBalance xmlns="http://PegPayTelecomsApi/">
        <vendorcode>CCCCC</vendorcode>
        <password>RRRRRRR</password>
    </GetAccountBalance>
</Body>
```

';

```
    $response = $this->client->post($this->OAuthUrl,$this->RequestAccessBody,$this->RequestHeader);

    $soap    = simplexml_load_string($response->body);
```

Comment: xml to php ??? CakePHP version???  Add your PHP code.

Comment: Yes bro.. version is 3.5

Comment: Don't add code in comment, update your question.!

Comment: And read how to convert XML to Array https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/xml.html#loading-xml-documents

Comment: can you add a some example code for question

Comment: example https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html#reading-json-and-xml-response-bodies

Comment: That's less of a CakePHP problem, and more of a general PHP problem: **https://www.google.com/search?q=php+parse+soap+xml+string+site:stackoverflow.com**

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = $this->client->post($this->OAuthUrl,$this->RequestAccessBody,$this->RequestHeader);

$soap = $response->xml; // xml response as array

debug($soap);
```

**Read:**

**https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html#reading-json-and-xml-response-bodies**

Comment: thanks for you comments. but its not working,  $reponse->xml return empty value. but i print $response->body give some xml code so that code how can i change as a array in php. kindly help me. I mention my ouput in question. kindly check it.